# Rational Number of a given fraction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all rational numbers $\frac pq$ such that $\frac pq=\frac {p^2 +30}{q^2 +30}$. How can I go about it. If I substitute p and q by real values $\frac pq$ gets innumerable rational numbers

Answer (score 2):

After cross-multiplying,

$$\begin{align*}
p(q^2 + 30) - q(p^2 + 30) &= 0 \\
pq(q - p) - 30(q - p) &= 0 \\
(pq - 30)(q - p) &= 0
\end{align*}$$

You can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $p,q$ to be coprime integers,

On cross multiplication & simplification we have $$(p-q)(p\cdot q-30)=0$$

As $(p,q)=1$  if $p=q,p=q=1$

Otherwise, $p\cdot q=30$ which does have **finite** number of solutions